# Show the_date with link

Tags: date-time

i try show the_date with link to same date!

```
 <?php the_date('l j F Y', '<tr>
 <th colspan="3"><a href="<?php the_date('Y/m/d'); ?>" rel="bookmark">', '</th>
 </tr>'); ?>
```

Comment: are you doing that inside The Loop?

Comment: yes.inside The Loop

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<?php 
$archive_year  = get_the_time('Y'); 
$archive_month = get_the_time('m'); 
$archive_day   = get_the_time('d'); 
?>
<a href="<?php echo get_day_link( $archive_year, $archive_month, $archive_day); ?>"><?php the_date('Y/m/d'); ?></a>
```

HTML result:

```
<a href="http://example.com/2015/09/07">2015/09/07</a>
```

Comment: I want show one time, such as: the_date

Comment: Can you write an example of html result?

Comment: <a href="http://example.com/2015/09/07">2015/09/07</a>
    
    <a href="http://example.com/title-post-from-this-date">title post from this date</a>
    
    <a href="http://example.com/2015/09/06">2015/09/06</a>
    <a href="http://example.com/title-post-from-this-date">title post from this date</a>
    
    <a href="http://example.com/2015/09/05">2015/09/05</a>
    <a href="http://example.com/title-post-from-this-date">title post from this date</a>

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
$archive_year  = get_the_time('Y'); 
$archive_month = get_the_time('m'); 
$archive_day   = get_the_time('d'); 
?>
<a href="<?php echo get_day_link( $archive_year, $archive_month, $archive_day); ?>"><?php the_date('Y/m/d'); ?></a>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
```

HTML result:

```
<a href="http://example.com/2015/09/07">2015/09/07</a>
<a href="http://example.com/title-post">Title Post</a>
```

For example, if you want show the latest posts:

```
global $post;
$post_args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 5
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $post_args );

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        $archive_year  = get_the_time('Y'); 
        $archive_month = get_the_time('m'); 
        $archive_day   = get_the_time('d'); 
    ?>
        <a href="<?php echo get_day_link( $archive_year, $archive_month, $archive_day); ?>"><?php the_date('Y/m/d'); ?></a>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    }
wp_reset_query();
}
```